# COUNTIFS in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, countif

I have a table with rows containing different materials. For each materials there is a material number and a supplier.

My goal is to create a column in Power BI which counts the number of distinct suppliers that each material number was purchased from. I have tried different formulas with `DISTINCTCOUNT` and filters, but none of them worked.

Below is an example table with material numbers, suppliers and the desired calculated column:

| Material Number | Supplier | Desired Column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | Vendor A | 2 |
| A5 | Vendor B | 1 |
| A6 | Vendor C | 2 |
| B1 | Vendor A | 1 |
| B3 | Vendor B | 1 |
| A1 | Vendor C | 2 |
| A6 | Vendor D | 2 |
| B3 | Vendor B | 1 |
| C1 | Vendor A | 3 |
| C1 | Vendor G | 3 |
| C1 | Vendor F | 3 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of a calculated column.

First off we invoke `CALCULATE` since we need to change the evaluation context. You can use the `VALUES` function to get a 1-column table of the distinct values of a given column. Use `ALLEXCEPT` to return all rows in the given table for the given material number.

```
Suppliers = 
CALCULATE ( 
    COUNTROWS ( VALUES ( 'Table'[Supplier] ) ) , 
    ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table' , 'Table'[Material Number] )
)
```

[image: A]

Comment: works, thanks. I had it figured out by myself with this formular, which gives me the same result:             Supplier Count = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[Suppliers]), ALLEXCEPT('Table', 'Table'[Material Number]))

Comment: I think your measure is good too - it is syntactically equivalent to doing `COUNTROWS ( DISTINCT ( 'Table'[Supplier] ) )`. The difference between `VALUES` and `DISTINCT` is subtle but important - `VALUES` includes the inserted blank row on the table on the 1-side of the relationship if there are keys in the many-side table without a corresponding key in the one-side of the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a new column that COUNT the number of Suppliers per material Number?

Try this New Column:

```
CALCULATE(COUNT(Suppliers),'Material Number')
```